# Codeigniter dynamic routing not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

Below is my code

```
$route['default_controller'] = "products";
$route['products/([:any])'] = "category/subcategory";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I need to redirect if I get any argument after products/ to category/subcategory. I will use wildcard but still it is not working. Its give me 404 not found error.

Here is my category controller code:-

```
if( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class category extends CI_Controller{
    function category(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){
        echo 'index';
    }

    function subcategory(){
        echo 'subcategory'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You Must Define a 404 override and use  $route['products/([:any])'] = "category/subcategory/$1";

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['product/((\d*)[a-zA-Z_]*(\d*))'] = 'category/$1';
```

Try this it work's for you

Comment: Thanks to answer Ankit...but i want to redirect on category/subcategory. and i was try solutions that you give...but still its give 404 not found.

Comment: and there is only small letter after product/ that why i use ([a-z]) or ([:any]).

Comment: when call uri /category/subcategory it will call the function of product controller that name is subcategory.

Comment: the route i provide you work dynamically for all action of product controller you not need to write route for all action that belong to product controller and name of action may be ant thing that's way i add capital latter allso and number all so.

Comment: $route['product/subcategory'] = 'category/subcategory'; this route is specific to your problem

Comment: I have products list like 
Electronis
Mobiles

Now when you click on product than url become like

products/electonics

So, now i need to redirect on category/subcategory ( category is controller ) when i get any text after products/

Comment: $route['product/((\d*)[a-zA-Z_]*(\d*))'] = 'category/subcategory/$1'; try this in it elctronics is pass like a perameter .

Answer (score 0):

I get the solutions.

```
$route['products/(:any)'] = 'products/subcategory/$1';
```